# Change logo size on scroll using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, events

I am trying to resize the logo when i scroll down using the following event but its not working :

```
I am using both classes lrg-logo and sml-logo in my css still nothing is working.


$(function() { var logo = $(".lrg-logo"); $(window).scroll(function() {
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 80) {
    if(!logo.hasClass("sml-logo")) {
      logo.hide();
      logo.removeClass('lrg-logo').addClass("sml-logo").fadeIn( "slow");
    }
  } else {
    if(!logo.hasClass("lrg-logo")) {
      logo.hide();
      logo.removeClass("sml-logo").addClass('lrg-logo').fadeIn( "slow");
    }
  }
  });
  });
```

Basically my nav bar is fixed so it should work and i am using bootstrap 5

HTML :

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="">
        <img class="lrg-logo" src="./images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
      </a>
 </nav>
```

CSS:

```
 .lrg-logo{ margin: 50px;
            max-width: 105px;
           }

.sml-logo{ margin: 20px;
           max-width: 60px;
          }

 .navbar { background-color: rgba(97, 95, 95, 0.103);
           transition: 0.4s; 
           overflow: hidden;
           position: fixed;
          }
```

Comment: It's working for me when I test your code. Are you sure you have jquery initialized?

Answer (score 2):

I'v seen yours code in jsfiddle with jQuery 3.4.1 . Logo resizeing works good.

```
here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/6kn52jbm/


.lrg-logo{
            max-width: 105px;
           }
           
.sml-logo{
           max-width: 60px;
          }

 nav { background-color: rgba(97, 95, 95, 0.103);
           transition: 0.4s; 
           overflow: hidden;
           position:fixed;
           top: 0;
           left: 0;
          }
p{
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: thats insane i pasted my code isnide jsfiddle and it worked but on my visual studio its not working :/ i am using bootstrap 5

Comment: For me it's also works lunched on vsc live server. Check if all libraries are downloaded properly and seted in wright order. You can campare with my version of your code on github https://github.com/JanJacek/logo_sizeing_on_scroll.git